# how to communicate from ionic1 to native ios swift using custom cordova plugin

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to communicate from ionic 1 to ios swift native using custom cordova plugin for that I developed a plugin as per https://moduscreate.com/blog/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/ this doc. but I'm not able to communicate. I'm getting:

> -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["LiveConnectCordova486334569","LiveConnectCordova","echo",["jai"]]

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="com-fibase-ionic-ios-multivideo" version="0.0.1" 
xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> . 
<name>LiveConnectCordova</name>


<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
    <feature name="LiveConnectCordova">
        <param name="ios-package" value="LiveConnectCordova" />
    </feature>
    </config-file>

    <js-module name="LiveConnectCordova" src="www/LiveConnectCordova.js">
        <clobbers target="LiveConnectCordova" />
    </js-module>
<source-file src="src/ios/LiveConnectCordova.swift" />

<dependency id="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" version="1.7.2"/>
</platform>
```

plugin.js

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
exports.coolMethod = function (arg0, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, 'LiveConnectCordova', 'echo', [arg0]);
};
```

myswift class

```
 @objc(LiveConnectCordova) class LiveConnectCordova : CDVPlugin {
   func echo(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
      var pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
          status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
      )

     let msg = command.arguments[0] as? String ?? ""

     if msg.characters.count > 0 {

         pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
            messageAs: msg
        )
    }

     self.commandDelegate!.send(
        pluginResult,
        callbackId: command.callbackId
     )
   }
  }
```

Comment: what above plugin method call ? How ypu are calling this echo method from ionic app ?

Comment: Also `</plugin>` missing in plugin.xml

Comment: @CodeChanger cordova.exec(function(){},fuction(){},"LiveConnectCordova","echo",["jai"])

Comment: tag's there <plugin></plugin>. I didn't mention above

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `LiveConnectCordova.js` file code as mention below.

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
exports.echo = function (arg0, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, 'LiveConnectCordova', 'echo', [arg0]);
};
```

As you are calling `echo` method from your Ionic code.

Also Call plugin method like below.

```
window["LiveConnectCordova"].echo(
              param,
              function(res) {
                console.log("Response :", res);
              },
              function(err) {
                console.log("Error :", err);
              }
            );
```

Try above call in your app.

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I did same like as above. Even-though it's not working

Comment: what error you are facing ? is it same error which you mention in your question ?

Comment: -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["LiveConnectCordova486334569","LiveConnectCordova","echo",["jai"]]

Comment: @Bharath can you call your plugin method like above I have added plugin method call. Try and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: I tried as mentioned like that. But, I'm getting same issue